# MySQL get name of last added value on group by query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show in an index of videogame cheats and tips page where all the cheats available are listed, but i'm grouping the results by videogame and counting how many cheats the videogame has, this I can accomplish, but I'm trying to show the last added cheat to the game.

My query is:

```
SELECT a_games.game_id, COUNT(*) AS cheat_count, a_games.game_fname, a_games.game_logo, a_cheats.cheat_title FROM a_cheats
                LEFT JOIN a_games ON a_games.game_id=a_cheats.game_id
                GROUP BY a_cheats.game_id
```

this shows the first added cheat only.

I tried using max on cheat_id but the value cheat_title keeps showing the first added cheat.

Table a_cheats

```
cheat_id    type_id    member_id    game_id    cheat_title    cheat_body    cheat_date    
1        |  1       |  1         |  22      |  Truques V...|  Introduz...|  2014-10-...| 
2        |  1       |  1         |  25      |  Invulnera...|  Durante ...|  2014-10-...| 
3        |  1       |  1         |  25      |  Modo Debu...|  Durante ...|  2014-10-...|      
4        |  1       |  1         |  25      |  Charme In...|  Durante ...|  2014-10-...| 
5        |  1       |  1         |  36      |  Cabeças e...|  Começa o...|  2014-10-...|
```

Table a_games

```
game_id    genre_id    member_id    game_fname    game_sname   game_logo 
22      |  15       |  1         |  4x4 Worl...|             | 5259da0...
25      |  3        |  1         |  Akuji th...|             | 5287ae0...
36      |  25       |  1         |  All Star...|             | 5287daa...
```

So in the results Akuji the Heartless should show the cheat_title "Charme Infinito" which is the last added cheat for that game

query results

```
game_id   game_count   game_fname            game_logo                              cheat_title
22      | 1          | 4x4 World Trophy    | 5259da0527128_ava_4x4worldtrophy.jpg | Truques (Vários)
25      | 3          | Akuji The Heartless | 5287ae093e115_ava_akujiheartless.jpg | Invulnerabilidade
36      | 1          | All Star Tennis'99  | 5287daa2695ef_ava_allstartennis99.jpg| Cabeças e pés grandes
```

Comment: have you tried `ORDER BY a_games.game_id, a_cheats.cheat_id DESC` ?
and perhaps you need to show your db schema.

Comment: Tried it and doesn't work. I also tried using max() on cheats_id, cheats_date but only those specific fields get the last entry while cheats_title keeps giving the first entry

Comment: after seeing your schema, you can use `ORDER BY a_games.game_id, a_cheats.cheat_date DESC`

Comment: still giving the first entry cheat_title "Invulnerabilidade" :(

Comment: actually, using game_id and cheat_id shall work, there must be something else which is making it doesn't work. If using `date` is no use, I suppose you didn't store the time (hh:mm:ss) and all of those 3 cheats of Akuji are stored on the same day?

Comment: yes i'm storing the complete date / time. The first entry on 2014-10-27 21:26:54 the second 2014-10-27 22:21:32 and the third 2014-10-27 22:22:54

Comment: i see, you can take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems once you call `count()`, you can't control which `title` to pick later on (it directly gets the title of the earliest entry).
Thus, we can do what you want by calling the count later.

note: you can change `ORDER BY a_cheats.cheat_id DESC` to `ORDER BY a_cheats.cheat_date DESC` if you want it to be more reliable.

```sql
SELECT gameID,gameName,cheatTitle, COUNT(gameID) AS cheat_count
FROM (
    SELECT a_games.game_id as gameID, a_games.game_fname as gameName, a_cheats.cheat_title as cheatTitle
    FROM a_cheats
    JOIN a_games ON a_games.game_id=a_cheats.game_id
    ORDER BY a_cheats.cheat_id DESC
) ungrouped
GROUP BY gameID
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63f888/18

OR

```
SELECT gameID,gameName,cheatTitle, COUNT(cheatID) AS cheat_count
FROM (
    SELECT a_games.game_id as gameID, a_games.game_fname as gameName, a_cheats.cheat_title as cheatTitle, a_cheats.cheat_id as cheatID
    FROM a_cheats
    RIGHT JOIN a_games ON a_games.game_id=a_cheats.game_id
    ORDER BY a_cheats.cheat_id DESC
) ungrouped
GROUP BY gameID
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63f888/19

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm. Also didn't know about sqlfiddle. Handy tool. Thanks again